# jQuery UI - While dragging and dropping rows using Sortable, the space between rows increases

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am using jQuery Ui's Sortable widget to implement drag and drop functionality in table rows. The problem is that if I drag the 2nd and 3rd rows down a little(not enough for the following row to be displaced), the space between the rows increases. Now, if I actually do swap the 2nd row with the 3rd (by dragging the 2nd below the 3rd), a lot of space accumulates between the first and 2nd row. If the above steps are repeated, we can continue to increase space between rows

Initially,[image: Initially]

Finally,[image: Finally]

```
The code is as follows:

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.sortable.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#table tbody " ).sortable({placeholder : 'red',axis:'y',containment:'tbody'});
        $( "#table tbody" ).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
<style>
.red{
    background-color : red;height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em;
}
#table{
    border-spacing : 2px;
    background-color : light gray;
}
#table tr{
    background-color : yellow;  
}
body{
    background-color : gray;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="table">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="name1">Enter name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name1"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="name2">Enter name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name2"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="name3">Enter name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name2"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Its a bad use of tables, but there is some legacy code I have to tolerate

Also, why is the placeholder option not working ?

Comment: I don't see a placeholder in your code; however, in general it works only on (most) HTML5-compatible browsers. As for sortable; I can't even guess. A fiddle might help (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DMTcU/ I had to modify some of the CSS because fiddle has a CSS reset on it; but I can't reproduce.

Comment: placeholder option is specified in the sortable argument

Comment: Oh sorry, I should've been paying more attention. Yeah, not sure about that placeholder thing; you've done it the way I would have. :-/

Comment: @GregPettit I am able to reproduce the issue in Chrome using your jsfiddle sample. No idea why though. Inspecting elements reveals nothing abnormal.

Comment: @liho1eye Oh, you're right! I tried in Opera and Firefox and kinda stopped there. Reproducible in Chrome here, too. Browser style or CSS interpretation issue, then. Might be solvable with CSS tweaks but I'm not sure what those might be.

Comment: I've experienced the same thing (in Chrome) and hovering over the elements in the Elements pane highlights the tr elements in the viewport, and the tr elements w/ the extra space between don't appear to have any visible cause for why they don't abut.  In web inspector you can actually click a node in the tree and drag and drop.  When I do this with rows, the phantom space remains, so it's not something with the tr elements, but a 'phantom element' that web inspector doesn't display as a text node or anything else.  Maybe a webkit bug? Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: The spacing problem disappears when you remove the `border` on the table rows in the fiddle. Part of the solution?

Comment: The spacing problem disappears when you remove the border-space applied on the table

Comment: any reason why your using an old version of jquery? (jquery-1.3.2.min.js)

Comment: It doesn't work on even the latest version. @guido and @ MotaBOS - the spacing still increases when we drag one row over the other

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are loading a very old set of librarys, if you change your code to this two line the issue is gone.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If you want you can narrow jqueryui just to sortable and that is about 38kb

Comment: actually, I experience the issue on 1.8.16 (which is what I originally noticed it while using), but in updating to 1.8.18, I still see it happening.  

See my comment on the question about the 'phantom' element moving around.  That may help track it down.

Comment: Doesn't work even with these changes as @jinglesthula mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be related to the table border-spacing.  If you set the "table { border-spacing:0px; }" you will minimize the space creep--at most 1px if I give my table rows a border on my tests.

Are you able to add markup to the table cells?  If so, you can nest the label and inputs into a container that you can then use to create spacing.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div style="margin:2px 0;">
      <label for="name1">Enter name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name1"/>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to affect the issue in my case (the 1px extra is what I'm trying to get rid of).  If it helps, the extra pixel-width appears as soon as I move the placeholder enough that the item below moves into the dragged item's old spot, and it appears on the bottom border of the item above the spot I dragged the item from.